# LUKS encrypted Ubuntu disappeared from GRUB menu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I've been happily running a triple boot for nearly half a year with an unencrypted ubuntu 18.04, windows 10, and LUKS encrypted ubuntu 18.04 (not full disk). I rebooted from my unencrypted ubuntu into GRUB and the entries changed. `Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi, Windows Boot UEFI loader, Windows Boot UEFI fbx64.efi, EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi, and EFI/ubuntu/mmx64.efi` were not there before. My encrypted Ubuntu disappeared. Both encrypted ubuntu and windows work fine. I was not messing around with OSes or even installed anything immediately prior to this.
[image]

`$ sudo update-grub` outputs:

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-62-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-62-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-112-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-112-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-62-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-62-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-112-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-112-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

I can mount the encrypted partition and browse files fine on my unencrypted ubuntu. I'm reaching deep into my brain to try to come up with anything I did that could've broke things and I'm coming up empty.

Comment: have you already tried boot-repair?  It must be run from a live session

Comment: @Nmath yep tried boot-repair from a live session. My boot menu got cleaner but it's still missing my encrypted ubuntu. It suggested I decrypt and mount encrypted drives before proceeding (which I did before the message which makes me wonder if I did it right). It also picked up on my encrypted ubuntu in the advanced settings menu default os to boot to thing (which makes me think I did it right).